# Python Traceback Error: Invalid Literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, traceback

I read the answers to the Python questions on traceback errors, alas I don't understand the answers provided.  When I run the below code I get a traceback error if the  user enters nothing. How can I avoid it? Please give only specific and short answers. Thanks!

`Error: Python Traceback Error: Invalid Literal for int() with base 10`

```
def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = (raw_input(">>> "))
    how_much = int(next)

    if how_much < 50: 
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)

    elif how_much > 50:
        print "You greedy bastard!"
        exit(0)
    else: 
        dead("Man, learn to type!")
```

Comment: The error is obvious when you think about what the code is doing. Why should int() return with an empty string return something reasonable? Why? Explain it please!

Comment: Thanks, How must I change the code so that the user at that point is asked everytime he doesn't enter a value to enter a value

Comment: The user had better not enter `50` exactly either I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In extension to Burhan Khalid's answer, if you want to prompt the user until he/she has entered a valid number, do this:

```
how_much = None
while how_much is None:
    next = (raw_input(">>> "))
    try:
       how_much = int(next)
    except ValueError:
       print "Dude, enter a value!"
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get that is when someone simply hits enter, the program gets a blank string `''`, and then the program tries to convert `''` into int.

```
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So try this:

```
try:
   how_much = int(next)
except ValueError:
   dead("Dude, enter a value!")
```

Comment: Thanks, How must I change the code so that the user at that point is asked everytime he doesn't enter a value to enter a value.